# Configure StatSVN to send email with a list of revisions on the given day

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, statsvn

How to Configure StatSVN to show the revisions on the given day and trigger it to send email to certain people?

The whole source code lies in the TortoiseSVN repository, whenever the developers check in / commit the files, the report with the list of commits should be sent to the concerned people for the given day.

I am new to this, so I need some help to get around with this problem. Any approach / solution you have in mind?

Comment: Same day, only if it crosses 12 it would be next day

Comment: Yes.. the list of commits with the revision history , revision id and author name

Comment: The whole source code lies in the tortoise repository, whenever the developers check in / commit the files, the report with the list of commits should be sent to the concerned people fr the given day. I am new to this, so i need some help to get around with this problem. Any approach / solution you have in mind?

Comment: My question is how to use StatSVN to do the same?

Comment: There is no such thing as "TortoiseSVN repository". TortoiseSVN is a Subversion client so the question is pretty unclear.

Answer (score 1):

StatSVN is not the right tool for this.

For commit e-mail notifications, configure your SVN server with post-commit hooks as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501692/easiest-best-way-to-set-up-svn-commit-emails)

Comment: No worries, I have got the solution and implemented it long back.